# returning the mean of a file just by using def

Tags: python, csv, statistics, average, mean

how could I write to the new file(n) by using def function?I mean how can I return the function?

```
import csv
from statistics import mean
def calculate_averages(input_file_name,output_file_name):
with open(input_file_name) as f:
    with open(output_file_name, "w") as n:
        reader=csv.reader(f)
        for i in reader:
            name=i[0]
            l1=list()
            for index in i[1:]:
                l1.append(int(index))
            n.write(str(name)+','+str(mean(l1))+'\n')
        f.close()
        n.close()
```

the csv file:

```
sepehr,19,17,20,14,19
taham,13,17,16,15,15,14,18
salar,14,19,6,12,15,12,19
mahsa,13,19,18,19,20,20,17,11
```

Comment: What do you mean by _when I add a def function to the program_ ? Can you share both versions of the code? Also, the indentation of the code looks broken in some areas, like under the `with`.

Comment: You have a def function in your code (the `def calculate_averages`) — so what are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code sample, it appears that you're not calling your function properly. That is probably why you're not seeing any output. It's not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but you probably want something more like this:

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

def calculate_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):

    with open(input_file_name) as f:

        reader = csv.reader(f)

        for i in reader:
            to_print_1 = i[0]
            l1 = list()
            for val in i[1:]:
                l1.append(int(val))
            to_print_2 = str(mean(l1))
            s = str(to_print_1) + ',' + to_print_2
            print(s) 

calculate_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name)
```

I'm assuming input_file_name and output_file_name are defined previously in your program, and are passed into the calculate_averages function as strings, e.g. "somefile.csv" or "outfile.txt".

Overall, `return calculate_averages` is not doing anything because there is nothing named `calculate_averages` to return. In your sample, `calculate_averages` is a *function* with two arguments, which means if you want it to do anything, you must *call* the function and pass it the two arguments.

Comment: @martineau  when i write this code without def function, it return me the answer.but when i read this in a def function, it returns me nothing.what can i do?

Comment: @AMC  when i write this code without def function, it return me the answer.but when i read this in a def function, it returns me nothing.what can i do?